# Why is my site getting requests for URLs converted to lowercase?

Tags: url, apache, browsers, hacking

On my sites I am seeing requests for what would be valid URLs, but with the path converted to lowercase.

For example, a valid URL is `example.com/some-product-CAT12P0.html`.

In my Apache logs I'm seeing `example.com/some-product-cat12p0.html`.

This is happening on several sites I manage, and I cannot see any pattern in the user agent.

An example log entry:

> `45.55.65.212 - - [24/Jan/2017:06:36:57 +0000] "GET /educational-assessments-cat12p0.html HTTP/1.1" 404 6011 "http://www.example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/537.75.14"`

UA can be Win/OSX/iOS/Android etc and many different browsers.

The sites all run on LAMP stack. I use mod_rewrite to convert `CAT12P0.html` to a query string to pass to a PHP file.

I have of course checked my source HTML and sitemaps and all links are uppercase at the end as mod_rewrite expects.

Is this a bad bot, or could I be doing something to tell UAs to convert my links to lowercase?

Comment: What response do you get when requesting a "lowercased" URL? 404 HTTP status?

Comment: Yes, you can see that in the log above. And 404 is correct as it's an invalid URL for my sites.

Comment: Sorry, yes, missed that! Hang on, isn't the "Referer" in that log entry your home page??

Comment: Url's are supposed to be lowercase, you are the one with the "bad" practice :)

Comment: @DocRoot - yes the referer is my own site, which to me makes it more strange, as I sait in the question I've double checked all my links

Comment: @Martijn - where are you seeing this? It's a unix server so case matters. https://www.w3.org/TR/url/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator use mixed case like me

Comment: Is the "Referer" log entry literally `http://www.example.com`, ie. without a trailing slash? (Or is this a result of your exemplification?) If there is no trailing slash then I would say this is certainly a _bot_. Any browser will include a trailing slash on the home page URL - which is _required_ in order to make it "valid".

Comment: You may be on to something there - just checked and there is no trailing slash, and there is for valid requests. The same IP made 8 such requests at the same time, to 8 different invalid URLs, using 6 different real looking UA strings. To what end I wonder? And what can/should I do?

Comment: From the very beginning of the web, the unwritten rule is to make all URLs lowercase, not upper or mixed. The idea was to avoid issues like this. It is actually possible to take a URL in upper or mixed case and make it lowercase, but not lower or upper to mixed case. This is why mixed case should never be used. I say this for anyone who happens to come along as a warning. If you can convert your URLs to lowercase, that would be best for the long term. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

These are usually hits from bad bots.  Unfortunately, it is very common for bots to attempt to lowercase the entire URL.   I have a website with mixed case URLs.   I get thousands of hits per day for URLs that have been incorrectly lowercased.    Here are the top user agents that did so yesterday:

```
  20494 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Gluten Free Crawler/1.0; +http://glutenfreepleasure.com/)
    312 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GrapeshotCrawler/2.0; +http://www.grapeshot.co.uk/crawler.php)
    281 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
    252 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; proximic; +http://www.proximic.com/info/spider.php)
     77 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
     55 Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14C92 Safari/602.1
     20 YisouSpider
     15 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20120101 Firefox/29.0
     14 ADmantX Platform Semantic Analyzer US - Turn - ADmantX Inc. - www.admantx.com - support@admantx.com
     13 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

As you can see, there are usually a couple big offenders, but I had 120 distinct user agents that hit all lower case URLs on my site yesterday.

Even Googlebot has gotten some requests in.   That isn't because Googlebot itself has this problem, but because it finds all lowercase links somewhere on the web.   It isn't exclusively a bot problem.   Some people lowercase the whole URL before they link.   Some scraper sites post lower case URLs.   There is even an occasional content management software package that won't allow posting of mixed case URLs.

In short, while mixed case URLs are allowed by the spec, in practice it takes extra work to support them.   Because it is such a common problem, you  should be put "301 permanent" redirects from the all lowercase versions to the mixed case version.

Answer (score 1):

Using capitals in urls are allowed and it works, but the whole problem is that `/a` and `/A` are two different urls (just as in your case).

Because this is standard, it's not very hard to imagine that a crawler, or a bot, or anything that indexes calls the url lowercased or tries what happens if they do.

To avoid the situations you're in now, and to simplify urls, it's good practice to make all urls always lowercased. A good rule of thumb is that you should be able to *tell* an url to another person at the most simple manner possible (*"No no, uppercase C. No not the whole word"*).

Even if you want to use uppercase characters, which is easily done, you should internally redirect it to lowercase so that `/aaa` & `/AaA` are treated the same (unless you have a good reason not to)

- https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls
- https://wiredimpact.com/blog/never-use-capital-letters-urls/

Comment: I accept your 'case' for using lower case, and I may change in the future. But this does not explain why links on my site are being modified by the browser. I use the uppercase just at the end of the URLs as this triggers rules in my mod_rewrite.

Comment: Yes, this does not answer the question.

Comment: expanded with a small paragraph.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. Sure it does not answer the question directly, however, it is still excellent and valuable advice for future users. I can do something about the down vote, but not much. I wish I could do more. Cheers!!